# Tracking echo output with Xdebug (in NetBeans)

Tags: php, netbeans, buffer, echo, xdebug

After a dozen years of using a simple shareware text editor to write PHP, I'm finally jumping into the world of IDEs like it's 1999.

I'm playing around with debugging in NetBeans using XDebug. I see how I can set breakpoints or step through each line in the code and see what values are assigned to variables. Very cool!

However, I don't see what happens to anything that's been echoed or sent to the buffer.

Is there a way to see this, or does NetBeans assume that I'm assigning all of my strings to variables to be output at the end (which is how I usually do it anyway)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **[`ob_start()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php)** to buffer your output, and then copy it to a variable using **[`ob_get_contents()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-contents.php)**.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use the IDE and add the ob_get_contents() expression